# Updating DataGrid after deleting files

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF application that shows and deletes subfiles in gridview after selecting folder from `folderbrowserdialog()`. I have a Datatable and a `FILLER()` function to display subfiles in datagrid. When user clicks button, files are deleted. My problem is, when I delete those files, my datagrid does not refresh. I tried `DataGrid1.Items.Refresh();` but I dont know where to put it, it did not worked. In Winforms with same code, I did not encounter with this problem.Here is my `FILLER()` function:

```
private void FILLER()
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@PathBox.Text);

            Table = new DataTable();
            DataGrid1.DataContext = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Table.Columns.Add("Name");
                    Table.Columns.Add("Type");
                    Table.Columns.Add("Size");
                }

                FileInfo information = new FileInfo(files[i]);
                FileSystemInfo systemInformation = new FileInfo(files[i]);
                Row = Table.NewRow();
                Row["Name"] = systemInformation.Name;
                Row["Type"] = systemInformation.Extension;
                Row["Size"] = (information.Length / 1024).ToString();
                Table.Rows.Add(Row);


            }
            if (Table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataGrid1.ItemsSource = Table.DefaultView;

            }
        }
```

And my Delete part:

```
foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    FileInfo toBeDeleted = new FileInfo(file);
                    if (toBeDeleted.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-DayValue))
                        toBeDeleted.Delete();
                }
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: you must delete the file in your DataTable. your DataTable don't know if a file was deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are Deleting the file, you have to remove the Row from DataTable also. In other way, You have to regenerate the ItemSource by calling Filter method. (but this will cost performance)

Comment: I tried   `Row.Delete()` after Delete function but it updates grid like only 1 file have been deleted. But in real, all files had been deleted background.

Comment: In the for loop you have to find the rows, matching to the FileInfo and then you have to delete that row.

In another way, at the end of for loop regenerate the ItemSoucce for GridView.

Comment: I tried `for (int j = 0; j < toBeDeleted.Length; j++)
                    {
  
                        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = Table.DefaultView;
                    }` after delete but it did not work.

Comment: I did it by changing datacontext to itemsource.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried updating the item source when you delete that file? Because refresh will simply repaint the object. It will not update the item source.

Answer (score 0):

Well even refreshing the items should not update your gridview.
What you stored inside it are strings, not the actual files.

If you want to refresh your gridview either reload the files (pretty costly) or delete the string belonging to the file you deleted too

Comment: I could not get "delete the string belonging to the file I deleted". I hold 3 informations about file, 2 of them are in string type. How would I delete that?